# What is the more accurate rendering of 2 Thessalonians 1:9 “ruin” or “destruction”?

Tags: greek, historical-interpretation, afterlife, grammatical-historical

We read two different translations:

> “These will pay the penalty of **eternal ruin**, separated from the
> presence of the Lord and from the glory of his power,” ‭‭2
> Thessalonians‬ ‭1:9‬ ‭(NABRE‬‬)

Vs

> “who will pay the penalty of **eternal destruction**, away from the
> presence of the Lord and from the glory of his strength,” ‭‭2
> Thessalonians‬ ‭1:9‬ (‭LEB‬‬)

If the traditional doctrine of eternal conscious torment is true, why do most translators use the word “destruction” instead of “ruin”?

**Q**: **Which is the more accurate translation, knowing the word ὄλεθρον (olethron) is used in 2 Thessalonians 1:9?**

Answer (score 2):

In the NT the noun ὄλεθρος (olethros) occurs only four times:

- 1 Cor 5:5 - hand this man over to Satan for the **destruction** of the flesh, so that his spirit may be saved on the Day of the Lord.
- 1 Thess 5:3 - While people are saying, “Peace and security,” **destruction** will come upon them suddenly, like labor pains on a pregnant woman, and they will not escape.
- 2 Thess 1:9 - They will suffer the penalty of eternal **destruction**, separated from the presence of the Lord and the glory of His might,
- 1 Tim 6:9 - Those who want to be rich, however, fall into temptation and become ensnared by many foolish and harmful desires that plunge them into **ruin** and destruction.

According to BDAG we have:

1. **a state of destruction, *destruction, ruin, death***, in our literature always with a kind of transcendent coloring, eg, 1 Thess 5:3, 1 Tim 6:9, 2 Thess 1:9
2. **act of destruction, *destruction***, 1 Cor 5:5

I note that in the LXX it is used with a wider set of meanings, but the above is what it means in the NT.  Thayer is very similar.

Comment: Well informed presentation, +1

Answer (score 0):

The word ὄλεθρος has such a diverse meaning, it doesn't clearly tell us the meaning.  Passages with "eternal/everlasting punishment/torment" have a clearer meaning (Matt. 25:41,**46**[κόλασιν αἰώνιον]; John 5:29; Heb. 6:2; Rev. 14:11[no rest, day or night]; 20:10).

**Figure 1.** Hebrew words ὄλεθρος translated in the LXX (generated with Logos Bible Software).
[image]

Comment: Very insightful, appreciate it.  +1

Comment: Here's a highly debated related question: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/27088/luke-1619-31-lazarus-and-the-rich-man-literal-allegorical-or-a-mixture-of-bo

Comment: I'm not sure linking the Greek word in question, having several meanings, to Hebrew words with several different Hebrew words translated to the Greek word in question helps clarify the question.